# Python: fitting a straight line between first peaks in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, curve-fitting

I have this [2D array](https://ufile.io/o5d8a), that looks like this using `imshow`:

[image]

I would like to find an algorithm that fits a straight line that passes between the ends of the "fingers", in this fashion:

[image]

Any ideas how can I do it?

The 2D array data can be obtained from here http://dpaste.com/3H31X3G

Comment: Can you upload a raw black-and-white image to test on?

Comment: @Eric Yes, the array can be downloaded from this link - https://ufile.io/o5d8a

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to fit a straight line to the points corresponding to the maximum x values of each "finger" - so isolating those points is the first step, and then fitting a straight line to theose points is the second step. Is this essentially correct?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially correct. If it was a continuous field on the left it was pretty straight forward. But since it is oscillating in the vertical direction, I ponder what is the best approach..

Comment: @Ohm: How does it oscillate, is it then always 0/below a certain threshold? If so, you could do something like this: `y_i = max(x_i)`, where `x_i` is the ith row and then remove all values in `y` below this threshold resulting in `y_filter`. The a simple linear fit of `x_filter` vs `y_filter` should work.

Comment: @Cleb It might oscillate also in the x-direction, but I think you idea can be useful - I'll try to do it this way..

Comment: @Ohm: Would be easier to help if you posted a minimal dataset which one can easily copy and paste.

Comment: @Cleb I've uploaded the whole array to the link  ufile.io/o5d8a. You can also copy and paste a lower resolution from here - http://dpaste.com/3H31X3G